# jquery mobile button refresh not working programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have a table that is added dynamically to the dom row by row. every row has a button in the last'' of the row. With the option to remove.

I am having problems getting the id of the button or any attribute. However the styles are applied.

```
function makeLeague(){
var tableStart = "<table style='min-width:100%;' id='league-table-custom' class='league-table ui-responsive' data-mode='reflow'><th>TEAM</th><th>PLD</th><th>W</th><th>D</th><th>L</th><th>GF</th><th>GA</th><th>GD</th><TH>PTS</TH><th></th>";
var tableEnd = "</table>";
var tableMid = '' ;
var secondtab = $('#demo1');

leagueSize = league.length;

for(k=0; k<league.length; k++){
tableMid += "<tr>";
for(i=0; i< 9; i++){
tableMid += "<td> " + league[k][i] + "</td>";

}
tableMid += "<td><input type='button' class='remove' value='"+k+"' id="+k+"></td></tr>";

}




secondtab.html(tableStart + tableMid + tableEnd).trigger('create');
$('#demo1').trigger('create'); //tried many combinations/and on own
$('.remove').button();
$('.remove').trigger('create');
}

$('.remove').on('click',function(){
   console.log ($(this).attr.id);});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions where I am going wrong here. I read the jquery mobile docs and they state that the styled button get wrapped in a div. Would this effect my access? Or can I construct the function in a better way that will eliminate any issues.

Comment: Isn't `.attr` a method, which will be passed an argument (attribute name) to return a string of the attribute value? So `console.log ($(this).attr.id)` should be `console.log ($(this).attr('id'))`.

Comment: @DavidDomain I have tried both with the same result. They both fail. I think it is to with it not being correctly initialized. When I call the refresh or create method I get `Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on table prior to initialization; attempted to call method create`

Comment: I got this working I had to traverse the dom a little bit more. When getting the value I typed `$('#pageone').on('click', 'table .remove',function(){

console.log ($(this).attr('id'));

});` and it works. Not sure that is normal behavior and hope it works on all browsers. thanks for any input.

Comment: @FintanCreaven You could write your comment as a fully qualified answer, and accept it. People may not come here if they dont see that the question has an accepted answer. For the good of all : a good question deserves a good answer :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working I had to traverse the dom a little bit more. When getting the value I typed `$('#pageone').on('click', 'table .remove',function(){ console.log ($(this).attr('id')); });` and it works. Not sure that is normal behavior and hope it works on all browsers. thanks for any input.

Instead of `$('.remove').on('click',function(){
   console.log ($(this).attr.id);});`